# This is correct when using onClick in onBindViewHolder to avoid "do not treat position as fixed only use immediately and call holder"?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am working on an application that on the main screen uses RecyclerView to show attendance information of different groups of people, each element contains a list of the last 3 saved records ("Latest records" in the image):

[image]

Clicking the "Watch" button should display the attendance record for the corresponding date...

It turns out that sometimes there are only one or 2 attendance records, so I have to check the size of the list to assign the onClickListener of each element.

So if there are 3 or more items to display, you would have to add the code for the click events for date 1, date 2 and date 3.
In the event that there are 2 elements, it would only be for date 2 and date 3.
Lastly if there is only 1 element, I would add click event for date 3 only.

As you can imagine, there would be a lot of repeated code, so I decided to add the code for each date in different functions.

So here my question starts because commonly when I put the code for a click event in `onBindViewHolder` and use the `position` variable, it regularly shows me the warning "do not treat position as fixed only use immediately and call holder". I understand the problem but I realized that when I pass the `position` variable as a parameter to my click functions it doesn't show me any warning, I guess it's because Android Studio doesn't know that there is a `setOnClickListener` inside the functions.

So, these are the parameters that my function was using: `private void clcikDate1(TextView tvRecord1, int position, long idGroup, String date){` in this approach `position` was obtained from `onBindViewHolder` using `holder.getAdapterPosition()` I know this is wrong and now I show you the current approach:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Group group = (Grupo) mGroups.get(position);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    long idGroup = group.getId;
    List<AttendanceRecord> recordList = interfaceDB.getLast3Records(idGroup);
    if (recordList.size() == 3){
        //Visual elements code....
        clcikDate1(holder, date1);
        clcikDate2(holder, date2);
        clcikDate3(holder, date3);
    } else if (recordList.size() == 2){
        //Visual elements code....
        clcikDate2(holder, date2);
        clcikDate3(holder, date3);
    } else {
        //Visual elements code....
        clcikDate3(holder, date3);
    }
}

private void clcikDate1(ViewHolder holder, String date){
    int lastPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    long idGroup = mGroups.get(lastPosition).getId();
    holder.tvRecord1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clicssListener.seeRecord1Click(lastPosition, idGroup, date);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see now I pass the `ViewHolder` as a parameter and inside the function I get the `TextView` and the last position, my question is, is this correct? and another question would be: Is it necessary to get the `idGroup` variable again in the click function? because as you can see I have one in `onBindViewHolder` but I don't know if it is necessary to update in my click function

Comment: How do you manage displaying the latest records? Using a listview alike control or just creating textviews on demand? Your current approach might be working and can't be qualified as correct or false. Because it is your way of implementation. But I can say that there may be better implementations. It depends on your UI and functionality structure.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I probably didn't know how to explain my problem, my code works and I understand that there may be more optimal or less optimal ways... however the doubt I have arises because when I use the position variable in a click listener (which is inside onBindViewHolder) it shows me the warning but if I pass it to a function it doesn't show me any warning.  So is it correct to use functions passing my ViewHolder as a parameter or should I put the OnClickListener directly into the OnBindViewHolder even though this involves repeated lines of code?

Comment: *So is it correct to use functions passing my ViewHolder as a parameter*... Yes it is totally ok and better than writing repeated code. But I would recommend that you better move all the code related to view holder and implement it inside the view holder class.